# Accessing map member variable via pointer to the parent class using vector pointers of the parent of the parent class

Tags: c++

I have four classes in my code, class Data, class Sample, class Node, and class Tree.

```
class Data
{
private:
    map<string, double> m_DataVariables;

public:
    Data();
    Data(const Data &data);

    map<string, double> getDataVariables() const;
    void setDataVariables(const map<string, double> &value);
};

class Sample
{
private:
    Data *m_pData;         // Pointer To The Map Of DataVariables

public:
    virtual ~Sample()
    {
        delete m_pData;
    }

    Sample();
    Sample(const Sample &sample);

    // Data Variables      
    map<string, double> getDataVariables() const;
    void setDataVariables(const map<string, double> &value);
};

class Node
{
private:
    double m_numSamples;
    vector<Sample*> m_NodeSamples;

public:
   virtual ~Node()
   {
   }

   Node();

   // Number of samples for the node
   double getNumSamples() const;
   void setNumSamples(const double &value);

   // List of Samples
   vector<Sample*> getSamples() const;
   void setSamples(const vector<Sample*> &value);
};

class Tree
{
private:
    vector<Sample*> m_Samples;
    vector<Node*> m_nodes;

public:
    Tree(vector<Sample*> &Samples);

    // List of Sample
    vector<Sample*> getSamples() const;
    void setSamples(const vector<Sample*> &value);

    // List of Nodes
    vector<Node*> getNodes() const;
    void setNodes(const vector<Node*> &value);

    // List of Names that were used in building the tree
    vector<string> getPredictorNames() const;
    void setPredictorNames(const vector<string> &value);

    void CalcError(Node *node, const string &Name, double &error);

};

Data::Data()
{
    m_DataVariables = map<string, double>();
}

map<string, double> Data::getDataVariables() const
{
    return m_DataVariables;
}


Sample::Sample(const Sample &sample)
{
    m_pData                     = new Data(); //Map of Variables
    m_pData->getDataVariables() = sample.getDataVariables();
}

map<string, double> Sample::getDataVariables() const
{
    return m_pData->getDataVariables();
}

double Node::getNumSamples() const
{
    return m_numSamples;
}

vector<Sample*> Node::getSamples() const
{
    return m_NodeSamples;
}


void Tree::Tree()
{
    m_Samples = vector<Sample*>();
    m_nodes   = vector<Node*>();
}

vector<Sample*> Tree::getSamples() const
{
    return m_Samples;
}

vector<Node*> Tree::getNodes() const
{
    return m_nodes;
}
```

In CalcError(Node *node, const string &name, double &error), I would like  for each sample in the NodeSamples in class Node, iterate through DataVariables map in class Data and compare the passed name to the key in the map. If name matches the key, to read the value associated with the key and store it in a set. I can't make use of C++11 capabilities at this point. C++98 is what I can use.

In C# under visual studio this is simple using:

List Values = node.Samples.Select(s => s.DataVariables[name]).OrderBy(v => v).ToList();

but in C++ I am not certain on how to accomplish this. What I started with is:

```
void Tree::CalcError(Node *node, const string &name, double &error)
{
    vector<double> Values;

    for (vector<TrainingSample*>::iterator SampleIt = node->getTrainingSamples().begin(); SampleIt != node->getTrainingSamples().end(); SampleIt++)
    {
        for (map<string, double>::iterator map_iter = **Not sure how to access the map....** map_iter++)
        {
            if (name.compare(**Not sure how to access the key in the map**) == 0)
            {
                Values.push_back(**Not sure how to access the value in the map**);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your getter should return const reference to avoid copies (and so use iterator of same container).

Comment: You don't have to explicitly construct `vector` or `map`, their default constructor is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

A map iterator basically yields you a `std::pair<KeyType,ValueType>`, thus you can access the stuff like:

```
for (map<string, double>::iterator map_iter = DataVariables.begin();
     map_iter != DataVariables.end();
     ++map_iter) {
    if (name.compare(map_iter->first) == 0) {
                  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Access the key
        Values.push_back(map_iter->second);
                      // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Access the value
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42 Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You may get rid of one of your loop with `map::find`:

```
void Tree::CalcError(Node* node, const string& name, double& error)
{
    vector<double> Values;
    const vector<TrainingSample*>& samples = node->getTrainingSamples();

    for (vector<TrainingSample*>::const_iterator SampleIt = samples.begin();
         SampleIt != samples.end();
         ++SampleIt)
    {
        const TrainingSample& sample = **SampleIt;
        const std::map<string, double>& m = sample.getDataVariables();
        std::map<string, double>::const_iterator map_iter = m.find(name);

        if (map_iter != m.end())
        {
            Values.push_back(map_iter->second);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```